# Automatically setting implicit retain of self within blocks

Tags: ios, xcode, static-analysis

I am trying to perform static analysis using xcode by setting "Implicit retain of self within blocks" for all Libraries. I need to go manually set this flag everytime and each time i perform a force sync the flag gets set back to 'No' from 'Yes'. I would like to know if there any possible way of setting the flag to 'Yes' automatically using Xcode after performing a force sync?